# Same Data is being appended to all the elements of Jquery Accordian

Tags: jquery

This is my program which shows an Accordian .

I am creating an Accordian with some sample data .
On click of that Accordian  element, i am capturing the click event , once selected , i am loading the xml file , and appending data to the div .

But the problem is that , the appended data is being shown for all other Accoridain elements .

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.*, com.as400samplecode.util.*"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Basic jQuery Accordion</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
var xmldocu = '<categories><category id="2" name="Pepsi" ><products><product id="858" name="7UP" price="24.4900" /><product id="860" name="Aquafina" price="24.4900" /></products></category><category id="4" name="Coke" ><products><product id="811" name="ThumpsUp" price="24.4900" /><product id="813" name="Maaza" price="24.4900" /></products></category></categories>' ;

          $(document).ready(
            function () {
                $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3",          
                    autoheight: false,
                    active: false,
                    alwaysOpen: false,
                    fillspace: false,
                    collapsible: true,

                    //heightStyle: content   //auto, fill, content
                });

$("#accordion").accordion({
 activate: function(event, ui) {
var selectedeleemnt = ui.newHeader.text();
if(selectedeleemnt=="CoolDrinks")
{
$(xmldocu).find("category").each(function () {
 var categories  = $(this).attr('name');
  var str= '';
 var UL = $("<ul></ul>");
 str += '<li>' + categories + '</li>'; 
 UL.append(str);
 $("h4").append(UL);

});
}
}
});
});
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div style="width: 468px;">
        <div id="accordion">


 <%
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("CoolDrinks");
        list.add("Snacks");
        list.add("Other");
        %>

<%
      for(String item : list)
      {
          %>
          <h3><a href="#"><%=item%></a></h3>
          <div>
              <h4></h4>
           </div>
      <%
      }
      %>
      <%
      %>

    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem is with this line:

```
$("h4").append(UL);
```

It should probably be something like this:

```
$(".your-accordion-element h4").append(UL);
```

where `.your-accordion-element` is a unique selector for the accordion element to which you wish to append data.

Comment: You mean  it should be $(".accordion h4").append(UL);

Comment: I mean it should be a unique selector for the element that you're trying to append UL to. Currently you are appending UL to all h4 elements, so you need a more narrow selector.

Comment: So you mean to say the way i defined Accordian is wrong ?? and should i modify that ?

Comment: I am getting selectedeleemnt as Accordian selected eleemnt , Can i use selectedeleemnt in place of your-accordion-element ??

Comment: Sorry, I have answered your question with a general jQuery approach, rather than looking at your specific jQuery UI implementation. Looking more closely, my guess is that $(ui.newHeader).append(UL); would work, or simply ui.newHeader.append(UL);

Comment: Thank you for the answer , infact i assigned the this way   <h4 id="<%=item%>"></h4>  and appending data this way $("#"+selectedeleemnt+"").append(UL);  , now it works fine . thank you very much .